# AWS Amazon Linux EC2 Instance: apache user permission denied for write to directories

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, permissions

I am getting a permissions denied error when trying to write to the `system/cache` directory for the apache user and group (calling from HTTP :80 via web browser)

I have the folder permissions set like:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-8 system]$ ls -lah
total 48K
drwxrwsr-x 10 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 05:05 .
drwxrwsr-x  7 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 04:59 ..
drwxrwsr-x  2 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 05:05 cache
drwxrwsr-x  2 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 04:03 database
drwxrwsr-x  2 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 04:03 engine
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user www  924 Nov 24 04:03 file_merge.php
drwxrwsr-x  2 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 04:03 helper
drwxrwsr-x  2 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 05:02 library
drwxrwsr-x  3 ec2-user www 4.0K Nov 24 04:53 plugins
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user www 3.3K Nov 24 04:03 startup.php
```

Apache Groups are set like this (I realize not a good idea to set apache to root group, but for testing purposes...):

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-8 system]$ groups apache
apache : www root wheel ec2-user apache

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-8 system]$ groups ec2-user
ec2-user : ec2-user wheel apache www
```

I have a script that tries to write to the `system/cache/` directory which permissions are set to `rwx` for `ec2-user` and `www`. Apache is configured to use:

```
User apache;
Group apache;
```

Chaning config to use `www` group fixes the problem, but I am confused why I cannot get it to work w/ group `apache`??

```
User apache;
Group www;
```

Am I not understanding the way groups work on linux??

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a proficient Linux or AWS user, but try adding the apache user to the www group:

sudo usermod -a -G www apache

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then confirm apache is part of the www group

```
grep 'www' /etc/group
```

That seemed to correct the problem for me. Just an FYI, I set up my EC2 server following [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).